# What is the difference between Class myVar = new Class() vs var myVar = new Class() in Dart?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to study Dart and I noticed in the online documentation that if the `class` has custom `constructor` the example of initializing the `class` is like this:

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
```

Now my question is **what is the difference between this code and the previous one**?

```
var emp = new Employee();
```

I tested both in online sandbox and `constructors` are both invoked. When do I use which code?

PS I'm not sure if this was already asked since I don't know the term of it in Dart.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of var keyword in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Base on the top answer in your link, does it mean **it doesn't have any difference at all**? it is just a plain declarative(noise)? Sorry I don't have background in C#. I have background Javascript. So it's not that much clear to me. Thanks.

Comment: At least in C#, it is just a shortcut to avoid writing the type, when the compiler can find it out by itself. I can only assume that for Dart it is similar. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12416873/107625).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make any difference because Dart is inferring the variable type from the value you assign. You would typically mention a class when you don't initialize the variable :

```
var value; // This is a dynamic variable of null value
int value; // This is an int variable of null value
```

[More on inference and the Dart type system](https://dart.dev/guides/language/sound-dart#type-inference)