# Conditional Operators (??) issues in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

```dart
void main() {
  print("Conditional Operators:");
  // small if else
  var a1 = 100;
  var b2 = 20;
  var istrue = (a1 < b2) ? 'True' : 'False';
  print(istrue);

  // check if null or print name
  var name1;
  var check = name1 ?? "This is Null";
  print(check);

  var name = "Abdulelah";
  var checknot = name ?? "This is Null";
  print(name);
}
```

I don't how i fix this problem in line 16
yellow error said:

> The left operand can't be null, so the right operand is never executed.
> Try removing the operator and the right operand.dartdead_null_aware_expression

Comment: problem here:var name = "Abdulelah";
  var checknot = name ?? "This is Null";
  print(name);

Answer (score 1):

The variable "name" won't be NULL because you give to him the value "Abdulelah", so the right part `?? "This is NULL"` won't be executed, remove this right part and the warning will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Using `??` we provide default value in null case.

```
a = x ?? y
```

The above example shows that if `x` return/becomes null, `y` will be initialized on `a`. The fact becomes.

- if `x` is not `null`, then `a = x`
- if `x` is `null`, then `a = y`

Instead of using `if, else` we use `??` to provide null handler value.

The editor is acting smart here because it knows that `name` is not null, so the yellow message is saying you don't need to provide default value because left expression will never be null.

To create `null` variable, you need to use

```
DataType? variableName;
```

In this case you are initializing  `String` and you can do

```
String? name = "Abdulelah";
```

But this is not needed unless you want to initialize null value on `name` variable.

You  can check

- [Difference between `var` and `dynamic` type in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12416507/10157127)
  and [dart.dev](https://dart.dev/) for more.