# The element type 'int' can't be assigned to the map value type 'FieldValue' when trying to assign a new value

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I have initial data which works fine.

```
var data = {field1: FieldValue.increment(1)};
```

And it is also fine when I add another field to the data.

```
data.addAll({field2: FieldValue.increment(1)});
```

But if I set the value to 0, it won't allow me to.

```
data.addAll({field3: 0});
```

It will give an error of:
The element type 'int' can't be assigned to the map value type 'FieldValue'.

I tried doing this but still, have the same issue.

```
data[field3] = 0;
```

How will I set the `field3` to a specific value?

Note:
This is the full code.

```
DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> ref = db.collection('MyCollect').doc(uid);
var data = {field1: FieldValue.increment(1)};
data.addAll({field2: FieldValue.increment(1)});
data.addAll({field3: 0});
ref.set(data, SetOptions(merge: true));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a better understanding

you can use the `var` keyword when you don't want to explicitly give a type but its value decides its type, and for the next operations/assignments, it will only accept that specific type that it took from the first time.

On the other hand, the `dynamic` keyword is used also to not explicitly set a type for a variable, but every other type is valid for it.

```
var a = "text";
a = "text2"; // ok
a = 1; // throws the error

dynamic b = "text";
b = "text2"; // ok
b = 1; // also ok
```

in your case, you're using the `var` keyword, so in the first value assignment it takes its type:

```
var data = {field1: FieldValue.increment(1)}; // takes the Map<String, FieldValue> type
data.addAll({field3: 0}); // 0 is int and FieldValue.increment(1) is FieldValue type,  so it throws an error
```

However, you can fix the problem and let your `data` variable accept any kind of element types by either using the `dynamic` keyword:

```
dynamic data = {field1: FieldValue.increment(1)}; // will accept it.
```

or, specifying that this is a `Map`, but the values of it are `dynamic`:

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = {field1: FieldValue.increment(1)}; // will accept it also.
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your answer. It is now working as per my expectation. Also, I understand how it works better now.

Comment: Good luck with your work

Answer (score 3):

check your dart type.

[Difference between "var" and "dynamic" type in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416507/difference-between-var-and-dynamic-type-in-dart)

the type var can't change type of variable. so check your code.

```
var data = {field1: FieldValue.increment(1)};
```

maybe data's type fixed something <String, FieldValue>

you can try dynamic type.

Comment: Hi rodpold, thanks for the reply. I didn't specify the data type. Do you mean I should put Map<String, dynamic> data instead?

Comment: Gwhyyy replied better answer. thanks.